# Unable to change html of body element

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I want to create a bookmarklet when clicked should replace html content within the body tag. I've used `document.write` and also `document.getElementByTag('body')[0].innerHTML =` but both overwrite the content within the head element too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<a href="javascript:document.write('<h1>Hello</h1>');">Click here</a>

<a href="javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML='<h1>Hello</h1>'">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the way to replace the body tag html without getting the javascript libraries removed?

Comment: @mhodes .. not clear!

Comment: Its work for me? --> https://plnkr.co/edit/yUjBA8DdHvpIoSM5JGhM?p=preview

Comment: Your problem is that you are doing an href that sets the javascript, which is essentially loading a new page with just your <h1>. You need to either set up a click handler in javascript, or use the onClick attribute like so: `<a href="#" onClick="document.body.innerHTML='<h1>Hello</h1>'">Click here</a>`

Comment: @mhodges the code needs to be within the href otherwise how will I drag and drop it as a bookmarklet?

Comment: @user5858 Ah, I missed the bookmarklet piece.

Comment: @user5858 I have posted an answer that I believe should work as a bookmarklet. Give it a try and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Oh this seems to be working and it looked like a puzzle.

Replacing with whole of page HTML (including the head element, libraries etc) makes it work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<a href="javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML='<html><head><script src=\'a\'></script></head><h1>Hello</h1>;return false;'">Click here</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was a bit tricky, but I believe I got it figured out. Basically how I did it was I went to a simple working bookmarklet and did a `decodeURIComponent()` on their `href` attribute and modified it according to what you are trying to do.

Let me know how it works for you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="javascript:((function(){var s=document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');s.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');s.innerHTML = 'document.body.innerHTML = \'<h1>Hello</h1>\''; document.documentElement.appendChild(s);})());">click here</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: He didn't want jQuery ;)

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:$('body').html('<h1>Hello</h1>');">Click here</a>
```

None jQuery way:

```html
<a href="javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML = '<h1>Hello</h1>';">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Added a none jQuery way.

Comment: your non-jQuery way is identical to the non-working code posted in the original question

Comment: Nope, look again, and mine works. Tested Chome & Edge.

Comment: Wrong. You are not understanding the original question. Please re-read. Your solution replaces the body HTML, yes, but it also wipes out the <head> tag which is what the OP is trying to avoid.